# Any good tutorial on using TortoiseGit with workflows?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Most git tutorials use command line which is fine but I'm looking for resources specifically showing *workflows* in *TortoiseGit* (note the emphasis on *workflows*, not just installation and basic checkouts / commits).

Any links / suggestions?

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing.  any success for answering this question on your own ?

Answer (score 14):

This is identical to our workflow in its simplest form which works quite well

http://uncod.in/blog/github-tortoisegit-and-organizational-workflow-tutorial/

And here some screenshot-enhanced explanation of branching and merging

http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/remote-branches-with-tortoisegit

Comment: Note that the GitHub team is working on a new Windows Git app that may improve upon the TortoiseGit way of working (currently in private beta)

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Can I apply for an invitation or something? Or is it completely private at the moment?

Comment: I think Phil Haack (@haacked) and Paul Betts (@xpaulbettsx) are working on it and I've seen participation requests on Twitter, which seemed to be accepted, but haven't tried myself.